# Bugs when updating Repository with 2 Angular Projects to Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I'm trying to update from Angular 8.2 to Angular 9. I'm doing this by following the official update Guide. I'm running the commands in the upper repository of the two projects.

For one project, everything is working fine and Angular got updated to Version 9.1 but for the other one I got several bugs of this schema:
[image]

This project is not working at all and it's not reachable in Chrome but interesting is that the errors  occur in files of the other project. So the 'dashboard' project is working fine but the projects I was actually serving in this screenshot doesn't.

These are my Angular packages versions:

[image]

Here's an example how I import Material Modules in App Module:

```
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

Comment: Is this error from a spec file?

Comment: I've just deleted the specs file of this component and the error still persists...

Comment: Which version  of angular material are you using? And can you show how you import material modules?

Comment: Did you verify that the module import entry points were updated? Angular Material v9 has removed support for importing modules from the root entry point (aka `@angular/material`).

Comment: Yes, sorry I've messed up pasting the imports from my app module. I've attached an example at the bottom of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I imported a component in both of the modules.

Thanks for your answers!